# PHP - how to read this XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<CallOverview>
    <Calls Count="2">
        <Call CallType="LandLine" Customer="this account" StartTime="2013-09-17 20:21:19 (UTC)" Destination="NL" Duration="00:00:05" Charge="0.045" CallId="158263673"/>
        <Call CallType="Mobile" Customer="this account" StartTime="2013-09-17 20:18:34 (UTC)" Destination="US" Duration="00:00:26" Charge="0.101" CallId="158263381"/>
    </Calls>
<MoreData>No more data available</MoreData>
</CallOverview>
```

I retrieve the XML like this:

```
function get_xml($url)
{ 
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
};
```

I receive the XML as desired, but I can't manage to extract the data the right way:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string ( get_xml($url_post) ) ;

echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";

    foreach($child->children() as $subchild)
    {
        echo $subchild->getName() . ": " . $subchild . "<br>";
        $role = array($subchild->attributes());

        foreach($subchild as $key => $value) {
            echo "$role $key $value";            
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
Calls: 
Call: 
Call:
MoreData: No more data available
```

I tried:

```
foreach($xml->Call[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object
```

Also when no calls have been made, there is no Call element. 
New to xml, so not sure if I can use child under child.

Comment: What happens? What do you mean `can't manage to extract the data the right way`?

Comment: What does this code output?  What do you want it to output?

Comment: I edited it, somehow I'm not getting the attributes from Call

Comment: hm you use $child twice in nested foreach

Comment: What do you expect `echo $child` to show?  What is your desired output?

Comment: Isn't calls a child and call a child of calls?

Comment: Also $role should be an array

Comment: This is just some test code, but I want to get the attributes for every call. So StartTime, Destination, Duration, Charge

Comment: [`foreach($subchild->attributes() as $key => $value) echo "$key $value";`](http://codepad.org/2D6ocEgx)(updated link)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the DOM-parser:

```
$dom_document = new DOMDocument();

$dom_document->loadXML(get_xml($url));

$searchNode = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName( "Call" );

if (!is_null($searchNode)) {
foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode )
{
    $Destination = $searchNode->getAttribute('Destination');
echo "$Destination";
}
}
```